# Will jQuery.noConflict() solve all conflicts?

Tags: jquery

I want to develop a widget that can be loaded anywhere in the body area of a website. What happens if I call `jQuery.noConflict()`, but after my widget more jQuery scripts are executed, that don't use `noConflict`? Will these then be executed with my jQuery library? If so, the alternative would be to use

```
var myJquery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

But then, how can I use third-party libraries with my own identifier, without changing their code from `$.xyz` to `myJquery.xyz`?

Comment: If the library has been written well then the fact that `$` is not a reference to jQuery shouldn't make a difference. The easiest way to tell is to try it and check for errors.

Comment: A well written plugin will attempt to use the `window.jQuery` rather than the `window.$`, in order to care less about if the `$` is bound to jQuery or not.  So it's really dependent upon the plugins being able to handle it.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/  references this under the "Protecting the $ Alias and Adding Scope" section